# How to get Docker Container stats using DataDog API?

Tags: docker, monitoring, api

I have a running DataDog-Agent on a Docker server.

Is there a function in the DataDog API to get the stats of every single container, so I could print the stats to an external Webpage?

Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but .. DataDog has a Docker Intergration, which when configured provides a status of every single container on a host. Then, by simply [querying](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#metrics) the DataDog metrics, you can see if  a particular container is up or not, or how many containers you have available per image, or what's the CPU consumption etc.